# How can I update values in a map?

Tags: java, collections

I am using a `TreeMap<Integer,Object>()` to store values.
Now my `Object` has a component, `Object.value()`, which keeps getting incremented as per values read from a file.
**So**, I evaluate whether the key exists and need to update value.
I do not understand how I can update values in a `Map` in Java.
I cannot just replace the whole record, as new values need to be added to the existing record value.
Is there a better way to do this than using a map? I used a map because I will keep searching for the keys.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Object is an actual Java type. So you don't want to use it has an example type ever.

Comment: I fixed your post's spelling and formatting. Note that Java is case- and spelling-sensitive, so if your code actually uses `treemap` or `Intger`, you'll get errors and be unable to build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well using a map is correct if you want to be able to quickly access your key-value pairs. If you're values are just `MyObjects` with a `.value()`, can't you get the object and reset that value?

```
MyObject myObj = treeMap.get(key);
myObj.setValue(myObj.getValue()++);
```

I'm using MyObject here as the poster was using `Object` to denote an example type.

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps use MyObject to avoid confusion?

Comment: Lol ok I'll do that. The poster should as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your "object" needs to have an setter which updates the value. So you just retrieve the object in question from the map, call the setter on this object, et voila. The only obstacle you must take care of is that whatever you do in your `setXXX` method does not alter the outcoming of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, as this violates the invariants implied by the `TreeMap` and will result in unpredictable behavior. You Object might look like this:

```
class AnObject {
   private int cnt;
   public void increment() { this.cnt++ };
}
```

You can pull it out of the `TreeMap`, call `increment()` and do not have to alter the contents of the `TreeMap` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do but if you just want to store objects with keys you should use a Hashtable. It allows to map keys to objects.

```
//create a hashtable
//the first template type is the type of keys you want to use
//the second is the type of objects you store (your Object)
Hashtable <Integer,MyObject> myHashtable = new Hashtable <Integer,MyObject> ();

//Now you create your object, and set one of its fields to 4.
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setValue(4);

//You insert the object into the hashtable, with the key 0.
myHashtable.put(0,obj);

//Now if you want to change the value of an object in the hashtable, you have to retrieve it from its key, change the value by yourself then re-insert the object into the hashtable.
MyObject obj2 = myHashtable.get(0);

obj.setValue(obj.getValue() + 2);

//This will erase the previous object mapped with the key 0.
myHashtable.put(0,obj);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're probably confusing him by suggesting that HashTable is not a Map.

Comment: Also HashMap is preferred over Hashtable unless you have a particular need for synchronization.